# probabilistic distribution of a variable which are based on random imputs

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, random-variable, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

In practice, I have a variable **x**, which is based on **(b,c,d)**. We may have a physics based math formula to describe the relationship between **x** and **(b,c d)**, i.e., **x=f(b,c,d)**. Beforehand, we may know the probabilistic distribution of **b, c** and **d**. Are there any ways to know the probabilistic distribution of **x**? the function **f** can be complex, which is not similar linear relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at section 2 of these notes,

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec10.pdf

the complex function can be mapped to two real variables so thats not a problem.

For a numerical approach you can use a markov chain montecarlo.